# How to access key returned from Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, object

How to access an item in an object that is returned from `Promise.all()`.

I want to iterate throughout the array and get the title returned from each promise, but I can't access `Promise {}` and then any of the object inside.

```
[
  Promise {
    {
      _id: 5e09e4e0fcda6f268cefef3f,
      title: 'dfgfdgd',
      shortDescription: 'gfdgdfg'
    },
    qty: 1
  },
  Promise {
    {
      _id: 5e09e507fcda6f268cefef40,
      title: 'Test product',
      shortDescription: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the '
    },
    qty: 1
  },
  Promise {
    {
      _id: 5e09e507fcda6f268cefef40,
      title: 'Test product',
      shortDescription: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the '
    },
    qty: 3
  }
]
```

## EDIT

This is the code that creates promise array

```
const userId = req.user._id;
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const { inCart } = user;
    const results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < inCart.length; i += 1) {
      results.push(Product.findById(inCart[i].itemId, 'title shortDescription').exec());
    }
    await Promise.all(results);
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
      results[i].qty = inCart[i].qty;
    }
    return res.render('shop/cart', { items: results });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```

Comment: That's not a valid notation for objects. Can you show the code that constructs these so that we know what you're actually dealing with?

Comment: I've added the code that creates it.

Comment: Ah, there's your problem: `results` is an array of promises, and it will stay that array of promises - `Promise.all` doesn't alter the array. It creates a new array with the result values, which is what your `await` expression will yield.

Comment: Yeah, that is right, I just needed to assign Promise all to a new array. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` is an array of promises, and it will stay that array of promises - `Promise.all` doesn't alter the array. It creates a new array with the result values, which is what your `await` expression will yield. You should use

```
const userId = req.user._id;
try {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const { inCart } = user;
    const promises = [];
    for (const item of inCart) {
        promises.push(Product.findById(item.itemId, 'title shortDescription').exec());
//      ^^^^^^^^
    }
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
//        ^^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^
    // drop the qty assignment completely
    return res.render('shop/cart', { items: results });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess with `Promise.all` there is no chance to figure out which one called already the `resolve` function inside.

From [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) documentation which states:

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that fulfills when all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

In my example I have created the `Promise` elements with simpler objects like `{ title: 'first' }` for better representation.

**To achieve your goal** what is in your requirement, you need handle each `Promise` resolved state for example in a `forEach` just like in my solution instead of using `Promise.all()`. And by using `then` on each iteration you can access the object's properties which has been resolved.

Instead you can do something like this - obviously you need to apply to your structure:

```js
const promises = [
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ title: 'first' })
    }, 1200)
  }),
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ title: 'second' })
    }, 800)
  }),
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ title: 'third' })
    }, 2400)
  }),
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ title: 'fourth' })
    }, 3200)
  }),
];

Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log('all finished'));

promises.forEach(p => p.then(d => console.log(`${d.title} finished`)));
```

I hope that clarifies and help!

Answer (score 2):

`Promise.all` returns a [**promise**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). The only way to get the fulfillment value of a promise is by using a fulfillment handler.

> I want to iterate throughout the array and get the title of each promise

Promises don't have titles. *Fulfillment* values might, if they're objects with a `title` property.

So for instance:

```
thePromise
.then(results => {
    // ...use `results` (an array) here...
    for (const {title} of results) {
        // ...use `title` here, it's each title in the array of objects...
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error here...
});
```

Or inside an `async` function:

```
try {
    const results = await thePromise;
    for (const {title} of results) {
        // ...use `title` here, it's each title in the array of objects...
    }
} catch (error) {
    // ...handle/report error here...
}
```

(Or `for (const {title} of await thePromise)`, you don't actually need the `results` constant if you don't want it.)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to `await` the promises then you can get an array that contains objects

```
async function getData(){
    try{
        const data = await Promise.all()
        data[0].title // result : dfgfdgd
    }catch(e){
        // handle errors
    }
}
```